# Key Error while having the correct column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, keyerror

I am relatively new to programming , and I am trying to execute my piece of code in order to plot the values

My code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# set directory
df = pd.read_excel('Angle difference plot.xlsx', 'Sheet1')


# set plot
plt.plot(df['Angle'], df['RE Angle'])

# set label
plt.xlabel('calculated angle')
plt.ylabel('ground truth)')   
plt.title('angle accuracy plot')
plt.legend()

plt.show
```

When I execute the above code , I get the following error :

```py
 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1619, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1627, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Angle'
```

Can someone explain me why I am seeing this error ?

My excel file looks like this :

[image]

Any help is very much appreciated

Comment: Please [provide a reproducible copy of the DataFrame with `df.to_clipboard(sep=',')`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246/how-to-provide-a-copy-of-your-dataframe-with-to-clipboard). [Stack Overflow Discourages Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). It is likely the question will be down-voted. You are discouraging assistance because no one wants to retype your data or code, and screenshots are often illegible.

Comment: Please do follow @Trenton's guidelines as they will be helpful in solving your problem. Also check df.columns output and see if the "Angle" is in that. Make sure to check the trailing and leading spaces

Comment: In this case, the screenshot kind of helped. It does look like there is an additional space in the column header ` Angle`.

Answer (score 1):

## Fix the column names

- [`pandas.Series.str.strip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html#pandas-series-str-strip)

  - Remove leading and trailing whitespaces.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# set directory
df = pd.read_excel('Angle difference plot.xlsx', 'Sheet1')

# clear whitespace from the beginning and end of the column names
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()

# plot
plt.plot('Angle', 'RE Angle', data=df)
```

Comment: Yes , you are correct . I have the spaces in the beginning and towards the end of the trace . After fixing that , my code works as expected . Thanks for the catch . Very much appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

pls try this,

```
    plt.plot(df[df.columns[0]], df[df.columns[1]])
```

Comment: This won't resolve the issue if the OP has to do anything else with the dataframe.

Comment: I  fixed the column name , and it resolved the issue . Taken note of your suggestion . Thanks for recommending this

Answer (score -1):

I think you are wrong in this line: `plt.show`, it should be `plt.show()`.

This code runs well:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xl = pd.ExcelFile('d:/Python2020/20200614_1_tempexcelfile.xls')
# get the first sheet as an object
df = pd.read_excel(xl, 0, header=None)
# print(df.head())
# print(df.iloc[1:, 0])

# set plot
# plt.plot(df[df.columns[0]], df[df.columns[1]])
plt.plot(df.iloc[1:, 0], df.iloc[1:, 1])

# set label
plt.xlabel('calculated angle')
plt.ylabel('ground truth)')
plt.title('angle accuracy plot')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: How does this address the KeyError question other than simply not using keys?

Comment: Key is faster. And faster is better!

Comment: I  fixed the column name , and it resolved the issue . Taken note of your suggestion . Thanks for recommending this